# CSS column alignment using dt and dd

Tags: html, css, phpbb

I'm doing some styling and am trying to figure out why I can't get the column headers to align correctly for this phpBB bulletin board. When screen width decreases, I want the column headers to smoothly and consistently align under the list of forums and their metadata below it. Some sort of styling I think needs to be applied to the `.header dt`. I can specify a column width in pixels and it works for a while until screen width shrinks too much. Specifying width in percentages doesn't work either as the header alignment will not be consistent with the rows below them as screen width decreases. There's obviously a lot of styling going on and styles inherit from phpBB's prosilver style, but I need to make it consistent with the site's style.

https://phpbb33.adafruit.us/index.php

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

The solution in this case was to apply the following styling:

```
ul.topiclist dt {
    margin-right: -440px;
}
```